# Is there a way to prevent Kotlin from compiling a function with "dangerous characters" in the name?

Tags: kotlin, gradle, compiler-warnings

IntelliJ flags functions with characters in the title that might be dangerous for Windows as a warning. The compiler warning appears to be generated by [FirJvmNamesChecker](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/compiler/fir/checkers/checkers.jvm/src/org/jetbrains/kotlin/fir/analysis/jvm/FirJvmNamesChecker.kt). For an example, the function

```kotlin
@Test
fun `quotation marks "MAKE WINDOWS ANGRY"`() {
    assertTrue(true)
}
```

throws a warning. Instead of just showing up as a warning, I'd like that to fail to compile or at the very least fail some sort of other test.

Gradle has `kotlinOptions.allWarningsAsErrors = true` but I don't want *all* warnings to be errors, just this one. detekt has `FunctionNaming` but that doesn't appear to do what I need either, I want to restrict the names of functions in production code and functions in tests differently if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the option to treat a specific compiler warning as an error is **not possible** at the moment. There is a YouTrack [issue with the feature requested to track interest](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-18783). (Feel free to up-vote it)

Perhaps you might be interested to have a look at [ktlint](https://github.com/pinterest/ktlint), a Kotlin Linter built by Pinterest. (i.e. perhaps you can extended it with a custom rule to enforce JVM name checker)